# Export/Import AD Users including manager attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to import users from a csv file, which I exported from a different domain. Unfortunately the `manager` attribute gives me a hard time.

**1. What I have done so far (Export):**
I exported User attributes from **AD1** with the domain name **oldDomain.com** into **export.csv**. In order to generate the export.csv file I useed the following command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object givenName,sn,name,displayName,sAMaccountName,manager | Export-Csv -Encoding "UTF8" -path \\hostex\Share\export.csv
```

This will result to the following file:

```
"givenName","sn","name","displayName","sAMaccountName","manager"
"Test","User1","Test User1","Test User1","test.user1",
"Test","User2","Test User2","Test User2","test.user2","CN=Test User1,OU=Users,DC=oldDomain,DC=com"
```

**2. Problem with Import**

Afterwards I try to import/add the users into **AD2** which uses the domainname **newDomain.org**. My command looks like this:

```
Import-Csv \\hostex\Share\export.csv | ForEach { New-ADUser -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString Pass321? -AsPlainText -force) -Path "OU=Users,DC=newDomain,DC=org" -GivenName $_.givenName -Name $_.name -Surname $_.sn -DisplayName $_.displayName -SamAccountName $_.sAMAccountName -Manager $_.manager.Replace("DC=oldDomain,DC=com","DC=newDomain,DC=org") }
```

This leads to an `ADIdentityResolutionException`. Since the first line of export.csv has no value set for the manager attribute, the command tries to find the user identity `""` within AD2. This is impossible to find. Therefore the user is not added to AD2.

In order to resolve this issue I would like to add some kind of If-Statement, which sets the value for the manager attribute only if the equivalent value in export.csv is not null (`$_.manager -notlike $null`). Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably attempt to reference a manager account before that account is actually created. Separate account creation from assigning a manager to it. Also, empty fields read from a CSV appear as empty strings, not `$null`, so you need to compare to `''` to filter them out.

Try this:

```
$users = Import-Csv '\\hostex\Share\export.csv'

$initialPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Pass321?' -AsPlainText -Force

$users | % {
  New-ADUser -AccountPassword $initialPassword `
    -Path 'OU=Users,DC=newDomain,DC=org' `
    -GivenName $_.givenName `
    -Name $_.name `
    -Surname $_.sn `
    -DisplayName $_.displayName `
    -SamAccountName $_.sAMAccountName
}

$users | ? { $_.manager -ne '' } | % {
  $manager = $_.manager -replace 'DC=oldDomain,DC=com$', 'DC=newDomain,DC=org'
  Set-ADUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Manager $manager
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to build the complete command as a string with an additional line that adds the manager option to the end of the string if it exists in the data and then use Invoke-Expression to execute the command.

```
Import-Csv \\hostex\Share\export.csv | ForEach { 
$NewUserCommand = "New-ADUser -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString Pass321? -AsPlainText -force) -Path 'OU=Users,DC=newDomain,DC=org' -GivenName $_.givenName -Name $_.name -Surname $_.sn -DisplayName $_.displayName -SamAccountName $_.sAMAccountName"
If ($_.manager) {$NewUserCommand += " -Manager " +  $_.manager.Replace('DC=oldDomain,DC=com','DC=newDomain,DC=org')}
Invoke-Expression $NewUserCommand
}
```